# Experience Analytics, Each Single Page View Counting as Two

Tags: experience-analytics

We have a scenario where each view is counting as 2 with regards to Experience Analytics.  This is in 8.1 rev. 151207.

I'm verifying the duplicate views by using Experience Explorer, with the right-hand pane opened.  It starts at 1, then goes 3, 5, 7, etc.  It is also duplicating goal counts associated with the page.

[image: Duplicate View Counts]

I had considered if we had an Iframe on the page that would essentially make each request equal 2, but that is not the case.  Is someone familiar with when the view count gets incremented?

Comment: are you making any JavaScript calls that load something in on the page?

Comment: I looked and there are no XHR requests in the console.  That would be the only place to look, no?  I will look to make sure we don't have any other calls on the page to other resources that may trigger a view.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I may be experiencing something similar where stats show duplicate page views for each page within milliseconds of each other

Comment: Not on this project no- I don’t recall finding a solution. But on newer project I’ve seen the same behavior when JS calls were making backend calls.